# how to move app from production to beta android

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded my app in production by mistake. Now, I am trying to upload it to the beta version. and it says that:

> Upload failed
>   You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1.

What should I do to upload the same apk to the beta version and remove existing from production? I have unpublished the app. Do I need to wait for some time or any suggestions to overcome this issue?

**PS: I don't want to change package name and upload new apk on the server.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot publish an apk file with the same version code. You have already published an apk with a versionCode of 1. Simply update the version code in your Manifest.xml. For example:

`<manifest android:versionCode="2" ...>`

Comment: Ok.. got it. Can I use the same version name??

Comment: Yes the version name can remain the same

Answer (score 4):

On the right side of the Developer Console in your APK window there's a button that says "Switch to advanced mode." Activate advanced mode by pressing that button.

[image: picture of advanced mode button]

Once selected, a dropdown will appear under the "Actions" column for your APK, and you can select to move your application between alpha, beta, and production.Below's image shows what that menu looks like for an APK in beta.

[image: picture of drop down menu]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new release in Beta track (Open Testing) and instead of uploading a new bundle, choose "Add from Library" option and select the app bundle that you uploaded for Production. The version of the Beta app would be same as that in Production.