# How to change status release product to alpha/beta app android on google play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I'm using apk file and upload to Google play console, It's published on google store but now I want to change from release to alpha/beta to test before, 
But I have try to some ways but it can not change...

How to change from release app to alpha/beta app for user can test it ?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858098/how-to-move-app-from-production-to-beta-android)

Comment: @MD: Yes I see, but it seem so old to refer..

Comment: I think this not possible if it is already in release mode

Comment: @Basi: So If I unpublish release version and upload a new apk for alpha/beta, it's possible ?

Comment: In Manage Versions you have 3 categories: release, beta, alpha. You can follow same method to create beta or alpha versions.

Comment: Yes i understand your meaning, but when i using alpha or beta I must be publish release version, it seem not wrong in this case for me

Answer (score 1):

You can't move an APK that is already published to everyone (Production) to ALpha or Beta. But if you create a new APK with a new version code, you can publish that new APK to Alpha or Beta.